EJBCA server issue - ant runinstall failure
EJBCA ant runinstall fails with below error. ant deploy is successful
ejbca:initCA:

     [echo] Initializing CA with 'ManagementCA' 'CN=ManagementCA,O=EJBCA Sample,C=SE' 'soft' '<ca.tokenpassword hidden>' '2048' 'RSA' '3650' 'null' 'SHA256WithRSA'   -superadmincn 'SuperAdmin'...


     [java] 06:13:43.030 [main] ERROR org.ejbca.ui.cli.infrastructure.library.CommandLibrary - Error: CLI could not contact EJBCA instance. Either your application server is not up and running, EJBCA has not been deployed successfully, or some firewall rule is blocking the CLI from the application server.
     [java]
     [java] Please be aware that most commands will not work without the application server available.
     [java]
     [java] Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: EJBCLIENT000079: Unable to discover destination for request for EJB StatelessEJBLocator for "ejbca/cesecore-ejb/GlobalConfigurationSessionBean", view is interface
 
org.cesecore.configuration.GlobalConfigurationSessionRemote,
 affinity is None 

org.ejbca.ui.cli.infrastructure.library.CommandLibrary.findAndExecuteCommandFromParameters(CommandLibrary.java:88)

     [java]     at org.ejbca.ui.cli.EjbcaEjbCli.main(EjbcaEjbCli.java:38)
     [java]     Suppressed: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
     [java]             at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
     [java]             at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:777)
     [java]             at 

I have followed the steps mentioned in https://doc.primekey.com/ejbca/troubleshooting-guide/command-line-interface but no luck.
Any help is appreciated. JBOSS server log looks fine

It is resolved after adding socker binding to port 4447
